# Print only the first page of each group

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

My report adds a page break and resets a custom page number whenever a group changes. How can I print only the first page of each group?

Comment: just set the printer itself not the crystal report.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal itself doesn't have a great way for you to programmatically print specific pages. But there are a few ways to make this *kind of* work:

1. **Easy:** Make a formula that generates a list of which pages are ones you want to print. (It might output something like `1,2,5,7,9`, which you could copy and paste into the `Page Range` when you go to print.)
2. **Medium:** Make a modified version of this report that excludes any data you *don't* want to print. Figure out a maximum number of records that fit on a page (for example, `18`) and only take the first 18 per group. (This might be easier to set up with a custom SQL statement in Crystal.)
3. **Difficult:** Same as option 2, but you write suppression formulas for *everything* on your report. If `Page Number > 1`, the entire page goes blank. After printing you just remove the blank pages from the file. Tedious, but no ink wasted...